# Proving that Jordan's lemma can be used in integral

Tags: integration, jordan-algebras

I have the next integral:
$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{e^{ik(x-x')}}{m^{2}+k^{2}}dk$.

I want to use Jordan's lemma to solve this integral so I started with proving that I can use it. I know that we can use Jordan's lemma if $\lim_{|x| \to \infty}f(x)=0$.

In my case: $\lim_{|x-x'| \to \infty}\frac{1}{m^{2}+k^{2}}=0$

But I don't see how can I prove it.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{m^2 + k^2} \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$ for $k,m \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: But how I show that this expression is equal to zero at $ \lim_{|x-x'| \to \infty}$

Comment: You let $|k| \rightarrow \infty$ in this context, right? Since you take $z = |k|e^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C}$ for the contour. If not, please elaborate on the symbols you are using

Comment: But according to the formula if we have an integral that looks like $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(x)e^{ikx}dk$ , we can use Jordan's lemma only if $\lim_{|x| \to \infty}f(x)=0$. And this is why I put $|x-x'|\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I think that $f(x)$ should be $f(k)$. I am pretty sure and I understand your confusion with this typo

Comment: OK, got it. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with the rest of the problem.